Can Kubernetes Secrets be auto reloaded as env variables
I have a bunch of environment variables being read from Kubernetes secrets as follows:
            - name: SERVICE_MANAGER_CLIENTID
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: service-manager-subaccount-key
                  key: clientid
                  optional: true
            - name: SERVICE_MANAGER_CLIENTSECRET
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: service-manager-subaccount-key
                  key: clientsecret
                  optional: true

Now these are auto refreshed every few days for security reasons. How can I update these env variables automatically without restarting the pod?
These secrets are being read as environment variables in a Spring Boot application. Is there a solution that allows us to watch the secrets and auto-refresh the env variables
Thanks,
Prabal

It is impossible to change environment variables of a running process (in general).

Exactly as @zerkms said; consider to read this value from a db instead as an env variables. Alternatively you can create a new micro service on a different pod just to expose this variables throug api; in this way you do not have to restart you main service but jus the second one.

If you mount the Secret as files, or use Spring Cloud Kubernetes to directly consume the Secret, those things will update on their own, but environment variables can't.
